# JsonSchema conditional validation of sub-schema definition/reference

Tags: json, openapi, jsonschema, pydantic, json-schema-validator

I have a schema defined as below -

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "title": "Actor",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "actor_id": {
      "title": "actor_id",
      "description": "actor unique id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "actor_category": {
      "title": "actor_category",
      "description": "actor category",
      "enum": [
        "EMP",
        "MANAGER"
      ]
    },
    "actor_metadata": {
      "title": "actor_metadata",
      "description": "actor metadata json",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "actor_category": {
                "const": "EMP"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/EmpSchema"
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "actor_category": {
                "const": "MANAGER"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ManagerSchema"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "EmpSchema": {
      "title": "Employee",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "emp_uuid": {
          "title": "emp_uuid",
          "description": "emp-uuid, default actor",
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "emp_uuid"
      ]
    },
    "ManagerSchema": {
      "title": "Manager",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "manager_uuid": {
          "title": "manager_uuid",
          "description": "manager-uuid",
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "manager_dept": {
          "title": "manager_dept",
          "description": "manager department",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "manager_uuid",
        "manager_dept"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "actor_id",
    "actor_category",
    "actor_metadata"
  ]
}
```

Here, I'm trying to validate depending on `actor_category` property, trying to enforce schema validation using the key in parent - `actor_category`. For example, if `category` is of type `EMP`, then I want `actor_metadata` schema to match that of `EmpSchema` and vice versa for `ManagerSchema`.

Ive seen few examples around conditional-branching, but they all seem to be focused around primitive property types.  Im unsure on how to define conditionals for enforcing sub-schemas and definitions. Above schema keeps incorrectly validating the following payload -

```
{
  "actor_id": "XYZ-123",
  "actor_category": "MANAGER",
  "actor_metadata": {
    "emp_uuid": "be93dfd1-5bda-42fc-86b1-1166481ddac8"
  }
}
```

Im unsure on why the above schema keeps passing validations. Would like to know on what I'm missing out and on how to handle scenarios like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to achieve by the use of `oneOf` in combination with a `const` discriminator field inside the object that is used in the `oneOf`. In the simplest case, the pattern looks like below.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "oneOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/A"},
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/B"}
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "A": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": { "const": "A"},
                "a": { "type": "string"}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": ["type", "a"]
        },
        "B": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": { "const": "B"},
                "b": { "type": "string"}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": ["type", "b"]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the schema validates against one of the sub schemas, `A` or `B` (but not both). The two schemas have the common field `type` which always has to be `A` for the first branch and `B` for the second branch. In addition to any other requirements, both sub schemas `require` the field `type` to be set. That way it will always be clear which branch to take in the `oneOf` statement at the top.

So the above will validate this, since it matches `#/definitions/A`

```json
{
  "type": "A",
  "a": "some text"
}
```

and this since it matches `#/definitions/B`

```json
{
  "type": "B",
  "b": "some text"
}
```

but not this, since it matches neither

```
{
  "type": "B",
  "a": "some text"
}
```

When applied to your case, it would be easiest to use the field `actor_category` as the discriminator/type field and move it into the `actor_metadata` sub schema. It then looks like this:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "title": "Actor",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "actor_id": {
        "title": "actor_id",
        "description": "actor unique id",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "actor_metadata": {
        "title": "actor_metadata",
        "description": "actor metadata json",
        "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/EmpSchema"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ManagerSchema"
            }
        ]
      }
    },
    "definitions": {
      "EmpSchema": {
        "title": "Employee",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "actor_category": {
                "title": "actor_category",
                "description": "actor category",
                "const": "EMP"
            },
            "emp_uuid": {
                "title": "emp_uuid",
                "description": "emp-uuid, default actor",
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid"
            }
        },
        "required": [
          "emp_uuid",
          "actor_category"
        ]
      },
      "ManagerSchema": {
        "title": "Manager",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "actor_category": {
                "title": "actor_category",
                "description": "actor category",
                "const": "MANAGER"
            },
            "manager_uuid": {
                "title": "manager_uuid",
                "description": "manager-uuid",
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid"
            },
            "manager_dept": {
                "title": "manager_dept",
                "description": "manager department",
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
          "manager_uuid",
          "manager_dept",
          "actor_category"
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "actor_id",
      "actor_metadata"
    ]
}
```

Using this pattern, it would also be possible to get to the exact structure you were showing above, or to get rid of the extra layer that `actor_metadata` introduces entirely, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daniel Schneider but can you point out why my schema definition doesn't work ? Ive explicitly added a `false else` branch to the if-then condition and the schema still seems to fail.

Comment: Sorry. I looked at it but couldn't figure it out either. I have always had a hard time getting the more "imperative programming"-like features of JSONSchema to work for me, so I landed on the more declarative/matching method I laid you here. I use that extensively.

Comment: I think `properties` keyword when using within scope of object/attribute definition is limited to that specific object/attribute context. So, in my example, there is no way to refer to `actor_category` from parent or at the same depth. Work-around would be to introduce new discriminators into metadata object or use validation towards end.